# FTP Setup IIS 7 - Cannot login

Tags: iis, ftp

Ok, I should probably put some more Googling effort in, but....

Setup IIS and have a "site", have created an FTP profile. It's worked... however I'm getting the standard authentication dialog when FTP'ing. My username and password for server doesn't work.

Went back to IIS hoping can provide a user account to access the site. Doesn't seem possible.

How can I login to this FTP site???

Answer (score 0):

set everything to "Enabled" in FTP Authentication... it's worked, no security... but am on LAN so ok :-)